# How to get response from server every second in JSON?

Tags: php, ajax, json, webserver, httpresponse

I want to get response from server every one second, the output will contain some value which I need to process in front end.

In backend I am using some queries to read data from MySQL and return me output.

Things I have tried:

1. Ajax
2. Webserver Events
3. Amazon CloudFront

None of these work for me. Usually it takes 3-4 seconds to get me response,

classic example to see this working (getting output in one sec)

http://madbid.com

Please let me know if anyone has some solution for this

Comment: Its not working is not a usable description. What is taking ~4 secs?

Comment: Yes it is taking 4 secs, by not working I mean I need output in one sec if not then that thing is not working for me..

Comment: If you are unable to determine what is taking 4 secs, it is not possible for us to answer it obviously. Network requests are pretty fasts.

Comment: If I have determined then why would I ask question here.
I mean this portal is for asking question to our queries if I am not wrong

Comment: I don't want anyone to think for me, it is just simple whether you know or not, the way of asking my question may be wrong putting comments like you do it is just way of demoralizing the users to use SO